# add an image in centre of ion item ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="item item-thumbnail-left  thumb-centre thumb-right">

  <img src="img/carryout-icon.jpg"></img>
  <img src="img/or.jpg"></img>
  <img src="img/delivery-icon.jpg"></img>

  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item.thumb-right img{
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 10px !important;
  right: 20px !important;
  margin-right: 20px !important;
  max-width: 80px !important;
  max-height: 80px !important;
  width: 100%  !important;
}
```

How do I update this so as to have the image in the center

```
.item.thumb-centre img{
  position: center !important;
  top: 10px !important;
  max-width: 80px !important;
  max-height: 80px !important;
  width: 100%  !important;
}
```

Demo:

http://play.ionic.io/app/91deb2272019

Edit: Problem with verticle alignment of centre image
This is how it looks like in console.

[image]

Comment: There is no `position:center`, you have three images, which one you want in center? have you tried `text-align:center` on parent element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go: http://play.ionic.io/app/23c0460f51dc 
To align any element left or right you simply need [float](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) property , and set its value left or right. And for centralization you need just `margin: 0 auto` plus having parent div with `text-align:center`.
Your classes will be like this 
**CSS:**

```
    .images-parent{
      text-align: center;
    }

    .left-image{
      float:left;
      max-width: 80px !important;
      max-height: 80px !important;
    }

    .center-image{
      margin:0 auto;
      max-width: 80px !important;
      max-height: 80px !important;
    }

    .right-image{
      float:right;
      max-width: 80px !important;
      max-height: 80px !important;  
    }
```

And simply assign them to item and images tags this way 
**HTML:**

```
 <div class="item images-parent">
  <img src="img/carryout-icon.jpg" class="left-image"></img>
  <img src="img/or.jpg" class="center-image"></img>
  <img src="img/delivery-icon.jpg" class="right-image"></img>
  </div>
```

Comment: That did not work. Could you please update the demo and seeif that works?

Comment: @SimranKaur you have three images? do you want all of them centralized or only one?

Comment: I want only one of them centralised. One to left and one to right and one in centre. I have images appearing at left and right corners with given css but  not in centre. I want or.jpg to be in centre.

Comment: @SimranKaur i have edited my answer. Please check the updated demo in my answer.

Comment: You are a saviour :) Thanks a ton :D

Comment: One more thing, margin:0 auto did not centralize the image vertically for me. Why would be that?

Comment: margin:0 auto only centrlized an element horizentaly.Centralization techniques work horizantly. For verticaly you need more trick.

Comment: I tried vertical-align: middle for parent div but it did not seem to align it vertically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88930/discussion-between-mudasser-ajaz-and-simran-kaur).

Answer (score 1):

Put your img tag inside of p tag.

```
<p style="text-align: center">
    <img src=....>
</p>
```

I hope this work for you.

Comment: Worked for me ionic 5

Answer (score 0):

Your Css is not proper. Use  **margin:0 auto;** to center the image.
There is no css property like **position:center**

Are you looking something like this

```
.item.thumb-right img{
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 10px !important;
  right: 20px !important;

  max-width: 80px !important;
  max-height: 80px !important;
  width: 100%  !important;
}

.item.thumb-centre img{
margin:0 auto;
  top: 10px !important;
  max-width: 80px !important;
  max-height: 80px !important;
  width: 100%  !important;
}

.item.item-thumbnail-left{
  margin-left: 20px !important;

}
```

Comment: But it did not work. Could you please update the demo and see if that works?